# VS2019 c++ Import a .lib file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I'm using Visual Studio, and I'm trying to understand how static libraries (.lib files) work and how to use them.

I have a project with several cpp and h files that is configured to compile into a Static library.

[image]

Navigating to the Release folder I can see .obj files for each of the source files and a .lib and .pch files.

Now I want to use this library in a new project, so I create an empty console application and copy there the .lib file

According to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) to import a .lib file I just have to:

```
Before you can use the math routines in the static library, you must reference it. Open the shortcut menu for the MathClient project in Solution Explorer, and then choose Add > Reference.

The Add Reference dialog box lists the libraries that you can reference. The Projects tab lists the projects in the current solution and any libraries they reference
```

However I cannot see any library to import, so I'm stuck trying to use a .lib file created in another project in a new toy project.

What am I missing here? I want to be able to use all the functions inside this .lib file in my new project.

Thanks

Comment: You don't import libraries. You link them in the Linker setting. `Linker ->Input->Additional Dependencies` you also likely have to set the Include directory and maybe add a directory to the linker search paths. `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`

Comment: In the picture, It looks like you are looking at the settings for the library. You instead need to alter the settings for the project that uses the library.

Comment: I know that Add Reference works with projects in the same solution. Not sure about in different solutions. The `Linker ->Input->Additional Dependencies` setting works in either case.

Comment: The picture is from the project that compiles into a static library. I'll try the linker -> additional dependencies option

Comment: The tutorial assumes you'll put the two projects into one solution.  Wise thing to do.  If you don't then the IDE can't show you the library project and you have to link the ,lib file explicitly.  Be careful to not mix build flavors when you do that.  Linking, say, the Release build of a library in the Debug build of a project that uses the library typically ends up poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the memo how I just did it using Visual Studio 2022:
In order to use .lib file from a different solution, need 5 steps:

1. Create a new solution new project as Console App.
2. Make a copy of the .lib file and its .h file and paste them into a folder of this solution.
3. Add .lib file directory: Right-click on the application project node in Solution Explorer and then choose Properties. Left pane, under Configuration Properties ,in the "VC++ Directories" property page, add the path to the directory that contains the LIB file to "Library Directories"/Paths.
4. Add header file(s) directory: under "Additional Include Directories", which is under Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General.
5. Add .lib file to linker:  In the Linker > Input property page, add the name of the LIB file to Additional Dependencies.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/adding-references-in-visual-cpp-projects?view=msvc-170

Detailed example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160